# how to go around dividing by zero c++

Tags: c++

I'm very new to programming having only started because of a class I have to take.

In the lab we have to program a simple calculator (adding, subtracting, division, and multiplication) and then plug in sets numbers the teacher gives us. Of course two of of the sets of numbers have zero in them. How would you code it to say undefined instead of saying floating point exception (core dumped)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
    float d;
    float e;
    float f;
    float g;
    float h;
    float i;
    float j;

    cout << "Enter value for a\n";
    cout << "Enter value for b\n";
    cout << "Then press return.\n";

    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;

    c = a + b;
    d = a - b;
    e = a * b;
    f = a / b;

    g = sqrt (c);
    h = sqrt (d);
    i = sqrt (e);
    j = sqrt (f);

    cout << a << " value for a\n";
    cout << b << " value for b\n";
    cout << "value for c is " << c << " \n";
    cout << "value for d is " << d << " \n";
    cout << "value for e is " << e << " \n";
    cout << "value for f is " << f << " \n";
    cout << "value for g is " << g << " \n";
    cout << "value for h is " << h << " \n";
    cout << "value for i is " << i << " \n";
    cout << "value for j is " << j << " \n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't just go around dividing by zero you know.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps better, would be to sanitize your inputs. "If user input `0` for `b`, then say undefined, else, try to calculate."

You'll also run into the issue, of if `a` is less than `b`, the `sqrt()` function is going to throw an error as well (not designed to handle a negative input).

Comment: Nice one, catching the `sqrt` problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just check before the division if either number is zero
if(a == 0 || b == 0) f = 0;

Comment: That does not differentiate between the usually valid `0 / b` and the invalid `a / 0`. The asker wants to display an error message for the latter.

Comment: regardless the division is impossible if one of the two numbers are zero

Comment: The division is not impossible so long as `b` is non-zero, and your method does not differentiate whether there would be an actual error or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can use try catch (exception handling) if you know how to handle the exceptions or you can simply check if b == 0 then show your message instead of dividing the numbers.

Comment: As I write this, the only answer to mention exception handling. :-) It's an easy enough error to catch with out a `catch`, but there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the condition you're interested in, you can easily refer to it in multiple places:

```
bool isDivisionByZero = (b == 0);
if (!isDivisionByZero) f = a / b; else f = 0;

...

if (!isDivisionByZero)
    cout << "value for f is " << f << " \n";
else 
    cout << "value for f could not be computed (division by zero) \n"
```